# Issue with Login Authentication on StockX Using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Can someone help me with using scrapy to login to StockX.com? I am trying to build a web scraper to scrape price information off of stockx but I am unfamiliar with the type of authentication that Stockx requires to login. I have watched tutorials on using csrf tokens but do not see any tokens submitted in the form data when I login, so I am at a loss at how to authenticate logins using scrapy on StockX. Any help would be much appreciated.

Current code:

```
class StockXSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sx'
    # page_number = 2
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.stockx.com/login? 
 iss=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.stockx.com%2F'
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                            formdata={"username": "Gabiospi321@gmail.com", "password": "LitMari757"},
                                            callback=self.scrape)

def scrape(self, response):
     items = SxscrapyItem()

    all_div_blanks = response.css('div.product-header-media')

    for blanks in all_div_blanks:
        product_name = response.css('div.col-md-12').xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
        lowest_ask = response.css('div.en-us.stat-value.stat-small::text')[0].extract()
        highest_bid = response.css('div.en-us.stat-value.stat-small::text')[1].extract()

        items['product_name'] = product_name
        items['lowest_ask'] = lowest_ask
        items['highest_bid'] = highest_bid

        yield items
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you already have?

Comment: sure thing! posted.  Right now I get 403 errors when trying to run the scraper, which tells me my login is not functional.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead and do the following to log into [stockx](http://www.stockx.com):

### Code:

Using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) you would login by finding the email input and password input and then sending the `keys` for your login details. I am not sure if [stockx](http://www.stockx.com) have an api but if they did it might be easier to use that instead of logging in and scraping manually.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # you could use chrome instead

driver.get("http://accounts.stockx.com/login")
time.sleep(4)  # small delay before inputting login for page to load

driver.find_element_by_id("email-login").send_keys(
    "myemail@email.com"
)  # inputs your email

driver.find_element_by_id("password-login").send_keys(
    "mypassword"
)  # inputs your password

driver.find_element_by_id("btn-login").click() # clicks the login button
```

#### Video Demo:

[Video](https://streamable.com/lsisl8)

Comment: Hey thanks! I have used selenium before for logins.  I was not sure if it would work though or if StockX would block login in a similar way with no authentication token or cookie.  I will give this a try.